# Show that the chance that it falls entirely on one rectangular block is $\frac{(a-c)(b-c)}{ab}$

Tags: probability

A floor is paved with rectangular marble blocks,each of length $a$ and breadth $b$.A circular block of diameter $c(c<a,b)$ is thrown on the floor at random.Show that the chance that it falls entirely on one rectangular block is $\frac{(a-c)(b-c)}{ab}$

I thought over this problem,i found total number of cases as area of rectangular marble block,but i cannot find the favorable number of cases.Favorable number of cases cannot be area of rectangular marble block$-$ area of circular block,as the answer suggests.What should be the correct logic,please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to have the circle contained entirely in a block, you need to put it within an inner block of size $(a-c)\times(b-c)$ since the center should be placed at a distance of at least $c/2$ from any of the edges. Now, dividing by the total area $a\times b$ yields the desired result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The center of the disc
must be at least
c/2 from any of the edges.

Comment: shouldn't it be $c/2$?

Comment: You are right. I read c as the radius, not the diameter. Upvoted.