# Show that the probability that it falls entirely on one brick is $\frac{(a-c)(b-c)}{ab},( c<a, c<b).$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, geometric-probability

> Question: A floor is paved with rectangular bricks each of length $a$ units and breadth $b$ units. A circular disc of diameter c is thrown on the floor. Show that the probability that it falls entirely on one brick is $\frac{(a-c)(b-c)}{ab},( c<a, c<b)$

I tried to solve but ended up getting $\frac{\pi^2}{4ab}.$ What am I missing?Help!

Comment: How big is the disk????   What is the area where the center of the disk may land and keep the circle within the rectangle?  Divide this area by the total area of the rectangle.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457623/show-that-the-chance-that-it-falls-entirely-on-one-rectangular-block-is-frac?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The area where the disk center can fall divided by the total area is:

$$\frac{(a-c)(b-c)}{ab}$$

[image]

Comment: Why should we consider the centre? Why can't we just use the area of circle?

Comment: Because everything is determined by where the center lies.  Look at my figure.

Comment: Okay sir, now I get it. But the answer contains only c you used 2c. However your answer according to the explanation   is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!!

Comment: If the *diameter* is $c$, then indeed, there would be only $c$.  I'll fix that.  (I used *radius* when you didn't state the problem correctly.)

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake sir. I forget to write it.

Comment: So... perhaps and acceptance ($\checkmark$) is in order?